# The composition of a differentiable function and a continuous function.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

I am studying advanced calculus and I came across this problem. (The book is Advanced Calculus second edition by Patrick M. Fitzpatrick.)

Let $I$ and $J$ be open intervals, and the functions $f:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $h:J\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ have the property that $h(J)\subseteq I$, so the composition $f\circ g:J\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is defined. Show that if $x_0$ is in $J$, $h:J\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $x_0$, $h(x)\neq h(x_0)$ if $x\neq x_0$, and $f:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $h(x_0)$, then
$$lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{f(h(x))-f(h(x_0))}{h(x)-h(x_0)}=f'(h(x_0))$$.

I understand that the question is saying show and not prove which usually means that it is obvious but it already said that $f$ was differentable and so by definition $f'$ exists and furthermore it states that $h(J)\subseteq I$ so that $f$ is clearly defined for any $h(x)$. What is left to show. It seems like they are just rewriting the definition.

Comment: It isn't immediately clear, because the limit is as $x \to x_0$ rather than $h(x) \to h(x_0)$. But, since $h$ is continuous $x \to x_0$ implies $h(x) \to h(x_0)$, and $h(x) \neq h(x_0)$ so the limit is well defined.

Comment: No, the definition of the RHS is $\lim \limits_{x\to h(x_0)}\left(\dfrac{f(h(x))-f(h(x_0))}{h(x)-h(x_0)}\right)$.

Comment: That what I was missing. Thank you both.

Comment: "Show blah, blah, blah" usually means "prove blah, blah, blah" Where did you get the idea that "show" meant something less than "prove" in a context like your question? ("Show" is a nice Anglo-Saxon synonym for "demonstrate", a word of Latin origin, whose initial letter gives the "D" in Q.E.D., *quod erat demonstrandum*, or in English *which is what had to be proved*.)

Answer (score 0):

We can sketch a solution here using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limits. Our goal is to show that for every $\epsilon$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that

$$ x \in J \setminus \{x_0\} \text{ and } |x - x_0| < \delta \implies \left|\frac{f(h(x)) - f(h(x_0))}{h(x) - h(x_0)} - f'(h(x_0))\,\right| < \epsilon \;. $$

Thus, let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. $f$ is differentiable, so there exists $\delta_1 > 0$ such that

$$
y \in I \,\setminus\, \{h(x_0)\} \text{ and } |y - h(x_0)| < \delta_1 \implies \left|\frac{f(y) - f(h(x_0))}{y - h(x_0)} - f'(h(x_0))\,\right| < \epsilon \;.
$$

Since $h$ is continuous at $x_0$, there exists $\delta_2 > 0$ such that

$$
      x \in J \text{ and } |x - x_0| < \delta_2 \implies |h(x) - h(x_0)| < \delta_1 \;.
$$

Note that $h(x) \neq h(x_0)$ for $x \neq x_0$, so $h$ is injective. Then for any $x \in J \setminus \{x_0\}$, we also have $h(x) \in h(J) \setminus \{h(x_0)\} \subset I \setminus \{h(x_0)\}$.

Putting $\delta :=\delta_2$, we satisfy the above.